# Unable to see data loaded in clickhouse if i restart my clickhouse server

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, clickhouse

I am using clickhouse database for loading some real time metrics..so i created a table with the engine kafka and i loaded around 1 million metrics into it...but the thing is if i restart my clickhouse client and if i do select * from tablename i am unable to see the data loaded in it..how can i see that data?

```
CREATE TABLE cpuinfo (timestamp String, namespace String, data Float, unit String, plugin_running_on String, version UInt64, last_advertised_time String) ENGINE = Kafka('10.224.54.99:9092', 'cpuout', 'group1', 'JSONEachRow');
```

The above table i created and started collecting data as follows

```
select * from cpuinfo
```

and if i restart my clickhouse client and then do the same command `select * from cpuinfo` i am unable to see the data loaded...how can i see the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use MATERIALIZED VIEW for Kafka table as recommended in the [documentation](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/table_engines/kafka.html)?

If you use MATERIALIZED VIEW then all messages from Kafka will be inserted into the view. So in this case you should select from the view, not from the Kafka table.

If you do not use MATERIALIZED VIEW then you can query new messages from the kafka table only once. When you query again query will not return the same messages again, because it is already consumed once from Kafka.

If you need aggregated data then use SummingMergeTree as in the example. 
If you prefer raw data then you can use MergeTree.

The type of the timestamp column is String. What is a format of it? 
I suggest you to parse timestamp and insert it to Kafka as unix timestamp.
And then you need to re-create table cpuinfo with timestamp column with type UInt64.

If you do this then you can create view using these statements:

```
CREATE TABLE cpuinfo_t (
  timestamp UInt64,
  namespace String, 
  data Float, 
  unit String, 
  plugin_running_on String, 
  version UInt64, 
  last_advertised_time String, 
  DAY Date) 
ENGINE = MergeTree 
PARTITION BY DAY 
ORDER BY (DAY, timestamp) SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cpuinfo_view TO cpuinfo_t AS 
SELECT 
  timestamp, 
  namespace, 
  data, 
  unit, 
  plugin_running_on, 
  version, 
  last_advertised_time, 
  toDate(toDateTime(timestamp)) AS DAY 
FROM cpuinfo;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ....i didnt understand the example properly which they have given in the doc....how can i create a materialized view for the above cpuinfo table mentioned in the question...

Comment: Index granularity defines sparsity of primary key files. In the example I posted primary key/index is `(DAY, timestamp)`.
`index_granularity = 8192`  is a suggested  value for most cases.

You can read more here:

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/development/architecture.html#merge-tree

https://medium.com/@f1yegor/clickhouse-primary-keys-2cf2a45d7324

Comment: thanks....so now if i start collecting data from kafka and if i want to see that data on clickhouse what should be my query ` select * from cpuinfo_view ` or from which table i need to take that

Comment: Yes, you should select from `cpuinfo_view`

Comment: but if i do `select * from cpuinfo_view` nothing i am getting in that....but if i do `select * from cpuinfo` there i can see data ...how can i see data in cpuinfo_view which ll be saved

Comment: Do you have any errors in the log `/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log` when you publish message to Kafka?

Comment: `2018.01.30 05:20:46.697449 [ 24 ] <Debug> StorageKafka (cpuinfo): Started streaming to 1 attached views 2018.01.30 05:20:46.697530 [ 24 ] <Trace> StorageKafka (cpuinfo): Creating formatted reader 2018.01.30 05:20:51.698192 [ 24 ] <Debug> StorageKafka (cpuinfo): Stopped streaming to views` It is showing the above error

Comment: Do you have any other messages in the log when you publish message to Kafka?
You can also check clickhouse-server.err.log.
Did you change type of timestamp to UInt64 for the table cpuinfo?
You can check types with this query
`select table, name, type from system.columns where table in ('cpuinfo', 'cpuinfo_view')`

If you create tables and view as described it should work correctly

Comment: Ok now i changed timestamp datatype in cpuinfo to UInt64...but now i am getting error as `Code: 72. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000, ::1. DB::Exception: Unsigned type must not contain '-' symbol: (at row 1)` My timestamp looks like `2018-01-31 09:53:02.005395253 +0530 IST`

Comment: should i need to make timestamp in any other format like 20180131 09:53:02.0053952523

Comment: If you change type UInt64 you should send message to Kafka with timestamp as unix timestamp and not as String.

Comment: If you cannot change the code which insert message to Kafka then in table `cpuinfo` use `timestamp String`.  In `cpuinfo_t` `timestamp DateTime` and create view like this `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cpuinfo_view TO cpuinfo_t AS 
SELECT 
  toDateTime(substring(timestamp, 1, 19)) AS timestamp, 
  namespace, 
  data, 
  unit, 
  plugin_running_on, 
  version, 
  last_advertised_time, 
  toDate(timestamp) AS DAY 
FROM cpuinfo;`